# How do I get the value of href attribute when scraping web in dart?

Tags: dart

I am trying to get all the links on the web page with the help of Dart. I've tried [web scraper package](https://pub.dev/packages/web_scraper) but I were not able to get the value of the attribute href. Anyone knows the way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the web scraper package and can see it only works for Flutter which I have no experience with. So instead I tried to make something using the packages [html](https://pub.dev/packages/html) and [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) which seems to work fine and should also work with Flutter:

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> main() async {
  final page = await http.get('https://example.com');
  final document = parse(page.body);
  final hrefs = document
      .getElementsByTagName('a')
      .where((e) => e.attributes.containsKey('href'))
      .map((e) => e.attributes['href'])
      .toList();
  print(hrefs); // [https://www.iana.org/domains/example]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why, but sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: I debugged and saw that I am getting the document, but after parsing I get 0 elements in the list

Comment: Ah, I think I understand why, that is because the resource I was parsing is showing captcha and not the actual result

Answer (score 0):

@julemand101 solution should work as well since `web_scraper` is a wrapper around the html and http packages, but if you want to stick with `web_scraper` this should work:

```
final scraper = WebScraper('https://example.com')..loadWebPage('/test.html'); // Handle errors etc.
var data = scraper.getElement('a', ['href']);
```

I did not test it but ideally should return your data